# Euclidean triangle. Does this one exist

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Does $\exists$ a Euclidean triangle $ABC$ with $\sin(A) : \sin(B) : \sin(C) = \frac{1}{4} : \frac{1}{3} : \frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Using Sine rule  $$\frac a{\sin A}=\frac b{\sin B}=\frac c{\sin C}=2R$$

So, $a: b:c = \frac14:\frac13:\frac12=3:4:6$ multiplying the ratios by lcm$(2,3,4)=12$

Check whether $a+b>c,b+c>a.c+a>b$

Comment: Wait would this be an obtuse triangle then with side lengths $3$, $4$, and $6$?

Comment: @RichardCarpenter Exactly.

Comment: @RichardCarpenter, $\cos C=\frac{3^2+4^2-6^2}{2\cdot3\cdot4}=\frac{9+16-36}{2\cdot3\cdot4}<0\implies C>\frac\pi2$

Comment: Okay so I have an obtuse triangle with integer sides $3$, $4$, and $6$. What if I wanted to find the exact values of $sin(A)$, $sin(B)$, and $sin(C)$ then?

Comment: As $0<C<\pi,\sin C>0,$ From the previous comment, $\cos C =-\frac{11}{24}\implies \sin C=+\sqrt{1-\cos^2C}$ and so on